# How to sum values of JSON objects of same id?

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I'm trying to sum values of JOSN array objects that have the same id.

for example JSON array one is:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 3
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 5
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "value": 2
}]
```

and JSON array two is:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 2
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 3
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "value": 2
}]
```

I want to merge both JSON arrays while summing the values of similar objects (i.e. those of similar id).

Final result I want is as follows:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 5
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 8
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "value": 2
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "value": 2
}]
```

Kindly note that these are two separate JSON arrays (as illustrated above) and not duplicate objects within the same JSON array..
Thanks

Comment: It look like you mean "objects having the same id". If that is how you mean it, then you should not say "objects of similar id". Similar !== Same.

Comment: @PeterB the desired output clearly states what the OP means. your comment isn't welcoming and doesn't help or clarify the problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- Map the first array with summed values from the second array and remember the summed keys from the second array
- Add the second array keys that weren't added yet

```js
const foundKeys = new Set;
const merged = dst.map(({id, value}) => {
  const found = src.find(({id:id2}) => id === id2);
  found && (foundKeys.add(found.id), value += found.value);
  return {id, value};
});

src.forEach(item => foundKeys.has(item.id) || merged.push(item));

console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script>
const dst = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 3
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 5
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "value": 2
}]

const src = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 2
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 3
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "value": 2
}];

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Exactly what I was looking for.